# Theano with GPU works in command prompt but not in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, theano, spyder

I have installed theano with Python 3.5.3 and everything it requires to make it work on Windows 10, but when running the following test:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu
It says it uses the cpu when running from Spyder, and it uses the gpu when running from a command prompt

Any idea why?

Comment: I think you need to start Spyder from a command prompt to use Theano on it.

Comment: You're right, it works! Thanks.

Kind of weird though, on another computer it works without going through the command prompt

Comment: If that's the case, you need to do a restart. That's because (most probably) you added some environment variables needed by Theano, but they are not picked up until you do a restart (or log off/log on to your session again).

Comment: Restarting didn't fix the issue. But it as long as it works when starting spyder through a command prompt that's fine with me. Thanks for the help!